# Ruby on Rails 6: form submits an array of hashes via hidden field but gets blocked by <ActionController::Parameters ..... permitted: false>

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, forms, hash, actioncontroller

on the posts form errors it says 'User Must Exist'.

The correct parameters are being received including the user_id, but all the parameters are still rejected.
I suspect its something to do with the array of hashes as they come from another controller but via a form.

So when I inspect the Post params it says:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"email"=>"test@test.com", "user_id"=>"2", "items_bought"=>"[#<LineItem id: 3, product_id: 1, cart_id: 3, quantity: 1>, #<LineItem id: 4, product_id: 2, cart_id: 3, quantity: 4>]"} permitted: false>
```

**Simple_form_for @post**

```
<%= simple_form_for @post, :url => user_posts_path do |f| %>

  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <ul>

    <%= @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <%end%>

  </ul>

   <%= f.input :email, :input_html => { value: "#{current_user.email}" } %>
   <%= f.input :user_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { value: "#{current_user.id}" } %>
   <%= f.input :items_bought, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { value: "#{current_cart.line_items.to_a}" } %>

   <%= f.error :base %>
   <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

**Posts controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

 def new
    @user = current_user
    @post = Post.new
 end

 def create
    @user = current_user
    @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post_params])

  if @post.save 
    render plain:
    params[:post].inspect
  else
    render 'new'
  end

  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:email, :user_id, items_bought: [:LineItem_id [], :product_id[], :cart_id[], :quantity[]])
  end
end
```

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy


end
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: it could be due to _post.json.jbuilder.rb   ......   json.extract! post, :user_id,  :email, items_bought: [:LineItem_id [], :product_id[], :cart_id[], :quantity[]], :created_at, :updated_at
json.url user_posts_url(user,post, format: :json)

Comment: This looks like a really broken attempt at something that should be done with nested attributes or split into multiple controller actions.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question and ask about what you are actually trying to accomplish instead of just what you think the solution is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using your `post_params` method, change this:

```
@post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post_params])
```

to this:

```
@post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
```

EDIT: note that passing the user_id as a parameter is a security risk, someone can change the hidden field value. Use the current_user id instead of receiving the id from the form.

Actually, all the hidden info is retrieved from the current_user, you don't really need to use hidden fields since if you have access to the current_user you already have access to all that (id, cart items)

EDIT 2: if you want to have an array of hashes inside the :items_bought parameter, you need to use multiple hidden fields with specific names so it's parsed as hashes by rails.

Let's say you have this structure:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Foo',
    some_attr: 'Lorem'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Bar',
    some_attr: 'Impsum'
  }
]
```

If you send that as parameters you need multiple hidden fields:

```
hidden_field_tag 'items_bought[1][id]', 1
hidden_field_tag 'items_bought[1][name]', 'Foo'
hidden_field_tag 'items_bought[1][some_attr]', 'Lorem'
hidden_field_tag 'items_bought[2][id]', 2
hidden_field_tag 'items_bought[2][name]', 'Bar'
hidden_field_tag 'items_bought[2][some_attr]', 'Impsum'
```

When submitted, `params[:items_bought]` will be:

```
{
  '1' => {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Foo',
    some_attr: 'Lorem'
  },
  '2' => {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Bar',
    some_attr: 'Impsum'
  }
}
```

Note it's not the same, it's a hash of hashes and you have the ID if each hash as the key (that's the first part of the hidden field name `items_bought[1]` and `items_bought[2]`, and the ids are strings, not numbers.

You could also serialize the hash as a string:

```
hidden_field_tag :items_bougth, my_hash.to_json
```

and then on the controller do

```
param_hash = JSON.parse(params[:items_bought]
```

but I woudn't recommend this, it's a sign of something done more complex than it needs to be, you need to parse the parameters, use an extra library, etc.

Note you shouldn't do any of this with complex objects like LineItem as is, you talk about an array of hashes, an array of LineItems is not an array of hashes, you have to convert the objects to hashes first for both methods to work consistently.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply @arieljoud, you are correct I made the changes you recommend. It was done to see what would be passed from the session ie current_user. the problem is with passing an array of hashes to a database. I see what you mean in regards to passing that information in the controller instead of on the form. but is there a way of passing an array of hashes by changing the post_params method?

Comment: You shouldn't pass an array of hashes as a single parameter, what you have there is just the string representation of an array of LineItems, that's not how http parameters work, I'll edit my answer to show you how it should be done in your case, but I don't see the use case for that, it's hard because it's not the propery way to do that

Comment: Thanks @arieljuod for pulling me out of that rabbit hole. I'm going to pass that data at via the controller instead.BTW using  hidden_field_tag :items_bougth, my_hash.to_json  is a awsome im going to try that just to see how it goes.